# How do ${0##*/} and ${0%/*} work?

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards, parameter

I'm quite confused about the following regular expressions I found in a shell script:

```
${0##*/}
${0%/*}
```

How do they work?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Those are not regular expressions, they are examples of Bash's parameter expansion: the substitution of a variable or a special parameter by its value. The Wooledge Wiki has [a good explanation](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion).

Basically, in the example you have, `${0##*/}` translates as:

> for the variable $0, and the pattern '/', the two hashes mean from the *beginning* of the parameter, delete the longest (or greedy) match—up to and including the pattern.

So, where `$0` is the name of a file, eg., `$HOME/documents/doc.txt`, then the parameter would be expanded as: `doc.txt`

Similarly, for `${0%/*}`, the pattern `/` is matched against the *end* of parameter (the `%`), with the shortest or non-greedy match deleted – which in the example above would give you `$HOME/documents`.

See also the article on the [Bash Hacker's Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).

Comment: So... they didn't want to use `basename` and `dirname`? :D

Comment: One advantage is that parameter susbstitution doesn't spawn a subprocess...

Comment: @jasonwryan,can you elaborate the functionality of * in the above two examples? Or why we have to put * there. In specific, in the first example, * is placed before // ; while in the second example, * is placed after /.  What is the underlying difference?  Thanks.

Comment: The glob (`*`) indicates that everything up to and including the pattern will be deleted. Hence, for the beginning of the parameter, `#`, it is on the left and the end, `%`, working the other way from the right.

Comment: True, I was thinking that when I wrote it... but everybody who reads it knows WTF you're up to. ;)

Comment: It's not bash-specific, it's [specified](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02) by POSIX `sh`.

Comment: Also important is the expansion that occurs if the pattern does not match.