# what does "serial=${serial##*.}" do?

Tags: aix, ksh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do ${0##*/} and ${0%/*} work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22387/how-do-0-and-0-work)

```
0:root@SERVER:/ # 
0:root@SERVER:/ # serial=$(lscfg -vl hdisk1 | awk '/Serial Number/')
0:root@SERVER:/ # echo $serial                                      
Serial Number...............11BBGG11235
0:root@SERVER:/ #             
0:root@SERVER:/ # 
0:root@SERVER:/ # serial=${serial##*.}                              
0:root@SERVER:/ # echo $serial                                      
11BBGG11235
0:root@SERVER:/ #
```

What does exaclty

```
serial=${serial##*.}
```

do? Can someone please explain it? It's hard to google it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a parameter expansion in shell. For example:

serial=${serial##*.}  -- this will get the value in the last field delimited by '.' seperator. Grab the most last '.' in the value and print the rest of the data.

```
parameter     result
-----------   ------------------------------
${NAME}       polish.ostrich.racing.champion
${NAME#*.}           ostrich.racing.champion
${NAME##*.}                         champion
${NAME%%.*}   polish
${NAME%.*}    polish.ostrich.racing



parameter     result
-----------   --------------------------------------------------------
${FILE}       /usr/share/java-1.4.2-sun/demo/applets/Clock/Clock.class
${FILE#*/}     usr/share/java-1.4.2-sun/demo/applets/Clock/Clock.class
${FILE##*/}                                                Clock.class
${FILE%%/*}
${FILE%/*}    /usr/share/java-1.4.2-sun/demo/applets/Clock
```

For more examples look at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073