# What does this syntax mean "${i%.avi}.mp4"

Tags: bash, shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do ${0##*/} and ${0%/*} work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22387/how-do-0-and-0-work)

I have encountered this type of syntax somewhere on the web  :

```
for i in *.avi
do 
    ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i%.avi}.mp4"
done
```

how does this `"${i%.avi}.mp4"` and how can I use it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as a parameter expansion. Everything to the right of `.avi` is removed, and `.mp4` is concatenated onto the result.

If `$i` is "foo.avi", the result would be "foo.mp4". [BashFAQ 73](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073) has some good examples of other ways you can use parameter expansions for string manipulation.

Comment: I tried to edit your 2nd mp3 to mp4, but an edit for a single character is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

It will remove the suffix `.avi` from `$i` (if present) and then concatenate the result with `.mp4`.

This is called parameter expansion.

The standard ones are described here: 
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02

Your shell may or may not implement more of those, but if it does, using them will not guarantee portability.