# How to output files to another directory (Poppler - pdftotext)

Tags: io-redirection, poppler

I have a directory with a very large number of PDFs that I am converting to *.txt documents with Poppler `pdftotext`.  I have the following command that does the conversion of all the files.

```
for f in *.pdf; do pdftotext $f; done
```

The PDFs are on an external storage device without any additional space.  How can I redirect the output to a different directory?  That is, when each PDF is converted, it is written to another location rather than the same directory as the PDF.

Comment: I'll give it a shot ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was the suggested solution by don_crissti, and I am providing an explanation of it here for users just getting started with Unix and Linux.  Feel free to edit, as this summary was written by a novice.

```
for f in *.pdf; do pdftotext "$f" "/path/to/some/dir/${f%.*}.txt"; done
```

Now, let's examine each command.  Here is a standard for loop that is used to iterate overall all the files in the current working directory. `for f in *.pdf`.  In this command, `f` is used as the index. 
The next command converts the PDF to text.  This assumes the user has already installed [`poppler`](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/):

```
pdftotext "$f" "/path/to/some/dir/${f%.*}.txt"
```

`"$f"`is used to hold the name of the input *PDF* file and `"/path/to/some/dir/${f%.*}.txt"` specifies the path for the output *TXT* file, i.e. the target directory `/path/to/some/dir/` and the output file name `${f%.*}.txt` which is basically the input file name (`"$f"`) with the `.pdf` extension removed from the file name via [parameter substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22387) and a `.txt` suffix appended.