# Extracting filename from path string

Tags: shell, filenames

I have requirement to extract the filename from a given path for e.g. `/dev/user/test.csv`. I need location `/dev/user/` in separate variable and file name `test.csv` in different variable.
Could someone please suggest a solution ?

Comment: See also [How do ${0##*/} and ${0%/*} work?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22387)

Comment: Please add which shell you are using. Korn, Bash, Tcsh, etc...

Answer (score 6):

Normally

```
basename "/dev/user/test.csv" # produce «test.csv»
dirname "/dev/user/test.csv"  # produce «/dev/user»
```

In some shell's (like `bash` e.g.) you can use *variable expansion*

```
var="/dev/user/test.csv"
echo ${var##*/}               # produce «test.csv»
echo ${var%/*}                # produce «/dev/user»
```

If `/dev/user/test.csv` exist you can divide what you want by simple trick:

```
find /dev/user/test.csv -printf '%h\t%f\n'
```

Comment: Thanks that works for me but there is one problem I'm looping through set of folders if path is like "/dev/user" (without filename) I get "/dev" in path variable and "user" in file variable how can i avoid this ?

Comment: Much better if you show full code because to parce the output of `ls` command can lead to mistakes

Comment: Hi Thanks I'm facing another problem I appreciate if you can suggest something.....since Im looping through list of directories some directory names are like "dev user" , this list I store in array and try to get "basename" and "dirname" since there is space coming in between I'm not getting "basename" and "dirname" correctly its breaks up on space

Comment: @chhayavishwakarma U should provide correct looping. While I did not see you code I cannot advise you